# Force phone layouts on tablet

Tags: android, tablet

Is it in any way possible to make a tablet use the regular layout when there is a large one available?

So for example:

```
if(!user.payedForTabletApp) DO_NOT_USE_LARGE_LAYOUT();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can approach the problem:

**1)** Create two layouts: `res/layout/phone.xml` and `res/layout/tablet.xml`
**2)** Create layout aliases:
  ***2.1)*** `res/layout/main.xml` -> `res/layout/phone.xml`
  ***2.2)*** `res/layout-large/main.xml` -> `res/layout/tablet.xml`
  ***2.3)*** `res/layout-sw600dp/main.xml` -> `res/layout/tablet.xml`

By alias I mean something like this:

```
<resources>
    <item name="main" type="layout">@layout/phone</item>
</resources>
```

For more examples of layout aliases see [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html).

**3)** Update your `onCreate()` function in activity or `onCreateView()` function in fragment to use appropriate layout.

Here is an example for activity:

```
int layoutResId = R.layout.main;
if (!user.payedForTabletApp) {
    layoutResId = R.layout.phone;
}
setContentView(layoutResId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this wasn't the solution I hoped for but looks like there is not a better alternative... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this is no. Android handles the resource system for you.

You could how ever provide two different layout files, in you layout folder.

Something like `activity_home_normal.xml` and `activity_home_large.xml` obviously *I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS*!

Then you can do:

```
if(!user.payedForTabletApp){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_normal);
}else{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_large);
}
```

**BUT** I would look at charging your uses for other features not layouts. If I buy an app on iOS I expect the same app to work on both device sizes - same for android.

Layouts *optimise* user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, on the BUT part: the 'user' in my case isn't an end user but a customer/company who buys an app.

Comment: Ahh I see, OK So your talking white label style, well if someone does have a good solution to this I would be interested